# Yii default coll value in migration

Tags: php, yii

```
$this->addColumn('table_name','column_name','type');
```

How to add int type column with default value 0 ? There is not params for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it in `type` parameter like below:

```
$this->addColumn('table_name','column_name','integer default 0');
```

Or if you use `createTable` method, you can do like below:

```
$this->createTable('tblname', array(
            'id' => 'pk',
            'age' => 'integer default 0',
            ...
```